# Should we nuke or at least rename the nuclear tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The word [nuclear](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear) can be used in combination with other words, such as nuclear power, nuclear fusion, nuclear weapons, nuclear radiation, or nuclear physics, but doesn't make much sense on its own.

Should it be renamed or split up?

Some people conflate all nuclear issues, even being opposed to nuclear fusion reactors because it has the word "nuclear" in it, and I'd rather skeptics SE did not inadvertently legitimize such sloppy thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Let's nuke it! "nuclear" is an adjective and therefore probably not a prime choice as a tag :-)

No need to split it since there are only a few questions :-)

[nuclear-weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-weapons) [radiation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation) [physics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) [nuclear-energy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-energy) are way more than enough to cover the examples you make, in my opinion.

Comment: Only two questions?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear

Comment: I'm getting 23 questions.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm using the link above, I get 2!?

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot into a pseudo-answer.

Comment: I'm also getting 23 questions there

Comment: @AndrewGrimm thanks - confirmed 23

Comment: I've retagged the 23 nuclear questions. So now there's no questions tagged just nuclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pseudo-answer, but only because you can't upload pictures to comments:

[image: Screenshot of the nuclear tag with 23 questions]

The only reason I can think I'm getting 23 questions, and Sklivvz is only getting 2, is if he's hiding questions that are on his ignored tag list. I don't think that'd be the case, as a diamond mod can't afford to hide questions.

Edit: turns out he was looking at unanswered questions only.